# How do I create a custome link type in YouTrack that links to an external URL?

Tags: youtrack

We are using YouTrack for our project development.  There is an automatic feature that allows us to enter a project code and issue number, eg:  ab-101, in descriptions and comments and, when the description or comment is added, the text 'ab-101' becomes a hyperlink that links to that project's task number details page.

What I would like to do is also be able to enter text like, ex-1234 or ex:1234 (can be any format that would work) and when the description/comment is saved it is turned into a link that goes to an external URL, eg: ex-1234 becomes a hyperlink to http://somesite/somepage?id=1234

I think it would involve adding a custom
[link type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Link-Types.html) and then creating a custom [workflow](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Workflow-Guide.html) that did the parsing and transformations.

I did some Google searching but came up empty. I am hoping someone has done this and can explain how to set this up or share their workflow code to get me started.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid link type is an entirely unrelated YouTrack concept. Links created with link types can only connect two YouTrack issues; they are of no use when it comes to an external resource.

Still, a custom workflow may indeed help here. It should not rely on links of any kind, but rather check issues and comments for "ex-" text pattern and replace everything that matches with links. Be sure to check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Workflow-Spam-Blacklist.html#stop-word out for inspiration. This workflow does a somewhat similar thing, looking for text matches to reject them. Your version would be replacing them instead.